# REGEX - how to extract a specific number of rows from a text

Tags: regex, uipath

I need to find out how to extract a specific number of rows from a text( the number of rows that i want to extract would be variable).

In this case, i want to extract anything from `07/06/2021`, up to `SOLD FINAL ZI 1`

TEXT

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

07/06/2021 P2P  00.00

T d r 0000 R A cc  R A
r : aadr

REF. ------------------

P l p  00.00

P XX/XX/XXXX 0000000000 :00000000000 P R R

A B OO 0000000000 v e: 00.00 n 0000000000

c t 0.00 n

REF. ------------------

P2P  00.00

T d r  0000 R A c R A

rr : Saracie

REF. ------------------

P2P  00.00

T d r 0000 A. B c R A rr : Sanity

REF. ------------------

P l p   00.00

P XX/XX/XXXX 0000000000  00000000000 P R R

D OO 0000000000 V T: 00.00 n 0000000000 c

T 0.00 n

REF. ------------------

XX/XX/XXXX RULAJ ZI 1 3

SOLD FINAL ZI 1

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

In regex, i start with `\n(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` in order to get the data `07/06/2021`, but i don't know how to extract the rest.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try something like `^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[\s\S]+SOLD FINAL`

Comment: Thank you, this is what i used, and it worked: \n(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[\s\S]+SOLD FINAL ZI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow,

your question might not solve your actual problem. Do you REALLY want to "extract a specific number of rows"? This might be a [XYProblem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

I like [the solution from MDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658737/regex-how-to-extract-a-specific-number-of-rows-from-a-text#comment121338593_68658737) to extract everything up to `SOLD FINAL`:
`^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[\s\S]+SOLD FINAL`.
I like this because I guess you know the word at the end and not the number of lines. But we can't tell.

Anyway to give you the answer to your question (as your actual problem might look different than we expect) you can use this regex:
`^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}).*$(\n^.*$){n}`

```
^                     --> look at the beginning of a row
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) --> your regex for the date
.*$                   --> also take the rest of the line
(\n^.*$){n}           --> take the next n lines
     \n --> the line break
     ^  --> again: beginning of a new line
     .* --> as much characters as needed to match the next (non greedy)
     $  --> the end of a line
     {n}--> the number of lines you want to extract (replace n ;) )
```

Comment: Thank you, but actually i couldn't make it work with your code, but with MDR, that you also mention. 
Maybe it's because the site that i use, regexstorm.net, but i had to add the that regex an "\n" to make it work